# How can I override the Device Administrator security policy so that I can disable the lock screen?

Tags: security, lock-screens, exchange, device-administrator

On Android 2.2 Froyo, I added my Corporate Exchange Email account to the phone, however, the security policy set by the "Device Administrator" requires that I enter a 4-digit PIN at the lock screen and a maximum 10 seconds idle.

How can I hack my Android, through root access or otherwise, such that I do not need to follow this security policy. I am very annoyed at having to enter the PIN every time I want to use the phone, because I open/close it so often through out the day?

Comment: The proper way to do this is to ask your administrator to change the policy, and if you don't agree with their policy then don't attach your phone to their server. Also 10 seconds idle time is incredibly harsh, you must be able to make a legitimate case with them to change this. You might aslo find this previous question helpful http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/remove-corporate-settings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you buy the [TouchDown](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=NitroDesk,%20Inc.) app (30 day free trial available), the lock code will not be on the phone, but on the app. That's ever so much better.

Comment: Yeah except touchdown sucks and it doesn't actually sync with your other email or calendar.  You have to USE touchdown.

Answer (score 3):

There is an altered version of the 2.2 email app [here](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-hacks/57750-educational-froyo-bypass-exchange-server-policy.html) that disables the security features.  You need root to replace the app with this.

<sub>Originally posted as a comment by hagope</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Galaxy S, just dial `*#*#7594#*#*` and check the box. Your phone won't ask you for the password each time you turn the screen on (although you lose the lockscreen).