# Avoid Security for Outlook app in Android for lock screen

Tags: security, outlook

I had a concern recently regarding my lock screen privileges.

I recently installed Microsoft Outlook App for Android and with the installation they asked me to encrypt my phone with either pin, pattern or password which was compulsory and without that the outlook can not be started in the phone. After creating a pattern and logging in my credentials, I went to the lock screen menu from settings and what I find out is that I cannot go back to the normal "NONE" option for my screen lock facility.

I have a dead-end showing as:

> Disabled by Administrator, encryption policy, or credential storage.

I am really not a fan of cell phone security and am happy to keep it simple as it looks. Does anyone have a solution for this issue without uninstalling the application?

Comment: Why not choose a relatively simple (and relatively weak) password or PIN, such as "987654321"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I override the Device Administrator security policy so that I can disable the lock screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4391/how-can-i-override-the-device-administrator-security-policy-so-that-i-can-disabl)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your device and version of android you are running. You can goto Settings > Security > Device Administrators. Then uncheck the box for Microsoft Outlook App. That should allow you to go back to "none" for unlocking. Not sure how it would affect the app.

Comment: You will NOT be able to use the app any more!!