# How to cancel email account setup without accepting server specified security policies?

Tags: email, stock-email-app

This is a similar question to [How do I avoid the server-specified security policies for my work e-mail?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26885/how-do-i-avoid-the-server-specified-security-policies-for-my-work-e-mail) but whereas they are trying to use an Exchange email account without accepting the server's stringent security policies, I'm trying to **cancel** setup of the account.

The problem is, I can't open my Mail app without accepting these security policies. I get a dialog:

> [Server] requires that you update your security settings

...with two options - accept the security policies, or cancel, which simply closes the app.

How can I remove this half-complete Exchange account from my Mail app, when the Mail app won't open without accepting the policies and completing the setup of the account I no longer want to set up?

I'm on Android 5.0.2, non-root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it - you have to go through the phone's general settings, not the Email app.

Settings > Personal > Accounts > Exchange ActiveSync, then select your account, then there's a option "Remove" in the menu from the ... dots menu icon at the top right of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Just an update to the solution for Android 5.1: you may have to deactivate auto sync before selecting the exchange account to be able to access the settings where you can remove it.  Otherwise it kept kicking me back to the "accept/cancel" notification and not allowing access to alter the settings.

Auto sync is a checkbox option in the "..." menu on the account listing screen.  You can turn back on auto sync after the account has been removed.