# Get around Exchange screen lock policy

Tags: lock-screens, exchange, screen-timeout

I am accessing my company's email via Exchange. I'm running Android 6.0. The Exchange Policy sets the screen lock as soon as the screen timed out (immediate). Even though the timeout is set to 10 min, when I press the power button, it is considered screen timeout and I have to unlock. (power button instant lock is NOT checked).

I like to turn screen off whenever I am not using the phone to save battery. I found it very inconvenient to enter unlock code even after a short screen off. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Have you looked at [How do I avoid the server-specified security policies for my work e-mail?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26885/how-do-i-avoid-the-server-specified-security-policies-for-my-work-e-mail)?

Comment: It is a good read but I still want to stay within the Exchange ecosystem. Since there is no requirement for "power button instant lock". I wonder if there is an alternative way to make power button != screen timeout.