# Security options greyed out

Tags: settings, security, tasker, pattern-lock

There was a great thread on the same subject.

[Security options grayed out](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24341/security-options-grayed-out/69714#69714)

I am in the same situation where I need to keep the certificates on the android phone.  And the ActiveSync certificates greyed out the pattern and facial recognition login  options on my HTC one M8.

I can't delete them or otherwise I would be able to use ActiveSync for that server.

So I went to use the Tasker and secure Settings suggestion in the other thread link I mentioned earlier.  However, I am  completely stuck trying to figure out how I can have Tasker or secure settings override the  six digit pin requirement and allow me to do facial recognition instead.

Here is  where  I am stuck

Tasker -> Tasks -> Add Task -> action category: plugin -> Secure Settings -> Configuration: Secure Setting's Wake Up ->...  And Here is where I am confused.   I don't see any security setting or related Tasker Task to add to the "IF".

I'm a bit of a newbie with Tasker and Secure Settings. I looked in the documentation for both apps and not seen the next that I should take.

If you could help me solve this I would be very grateful.