# How do I remove corporate administrator settings?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, exchange, device-administrator

I have an HTC Desire C, just a couple of weeks old. I also have a new job and decided to add my work email account via Exchange activeSync, however once it became apparent that I was giving up rights and functionality (such as the screen pattern lock) for my own phone I decided to remove it.

I removed the administrator, which automatically removed the email account, however I am still unable to restore the screen pattern lock. I've restarted the handset a couple of times, no help.

I seem to have no options to view or delete and administrator accounts (presumably, and hopefully, because there are none now).

I've read the [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1568/16265) posted here and the answers but they don't help me sadly. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Android?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/how-to-remove-corporate-settings

Comment: Hi Al, it's Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0.3)

Comment: Thanks Bryan, yes that's the posting that brought me to this site but sadly it doesn't help me. Thank you all the same.

Comment: You don't clarify, so I'm asking: Have you tried to access `Notifications` > `settings` > `Security` > `Screen lock`, and personalize one?

Comment: Hi Zuul, yes. I only have the option to set a pin lock or password. The options to have no lock or a pattern lock are greyed out, saying on both: 'disabled by administrator, encryption policy or credential storage'.

Comment: In a [thread at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1511257), a user states: *I had the same problem when i tried to setup an exchange email account and installed a certificate.
Fixed it by deleting all certificates.
Settings>Security>Clear credintials* -- surely worth a try. Some more hints over there as well. [This thread at Android-Forums](http://androidforums.com/hp-touchpad/522034-disable-lock-screen.html) might prove helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Converting my comment into an answer, as it proofed according to its follow-ups:</sup>

In a [thread at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1511257), a user states:

> I had the same problem when i tried to setup an exchange email account and installed a certificate. Fixed it by deleting all certificates. Settings>Security>Clear credintials

So I'd suggest you just do that.

For additional information, also take a look at [this thread at Android-Forums](http://androidforums.com/hp-touchpad/522034-disable-lock-screen.html), which deals with the same problem you mention as example in your question ("screen pattern lock" -- here: disable lock screen).

Comment: Doing "Settings->Security->Clear credentials" worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to follow some simple steps to remove Exchange Active Sync password from Android.

Steps:

1. Settings
2. Backup & reset
3. Settings reset (resets phone to its original settings without erasing user data)
4. reset phone.

Mobile restarts automatically and you get happy.

Answer (score 0):

I went to **Security - Device Maintenance** and deleted the corporate email setting

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings, find themail "Accounts" section and click on the "Google" sub section. Your Google accounts should be displayed. Click on the account you don't want and the. In the bottom right corner of your phone screen there should be an option to " Remove Account". Click this and youp problem should be solved ^-^

Comment: The question isn't related to the user's Google account in any way, she used an Exchange account.