# Can't disable pattern screen lock

Tags: lock-screens

I recently installed PdaNet+.  To use wifi tethering it asked my to accept a certificate and set a screen lock pattern. I have since uninstalled it and removed the FoxFi certificate, but I still can't disable the screen lock (which I don't really want).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not quite the same as yours, but these questions about disabling the screen lock while Corporate Settings or Certs are on, or disabling the screen lock after they've been removed  may help you: [Install CA without having to activate screen lock](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28689/) / [How do I remove corporate administrator settings?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26768/) / [How to remove corporate settings?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/) / [Certificate Install without mandatory PIN lockscreen](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25491/)

Answer (score 32):

I just had that same issue today.

Go to `Settings`, and make sure you've removed Foxfi as an administrator. Go to `Trusted credentials > User > and remove Foxfi`. Then go back into `Settings > Security > and Clear credentials`. It'll let you change the lock code then! :)

Comment: It worked, but in my device : 5.1.1 it's located in Settings > Security > Certificate management -> Clear credentials

Comment: Clear credentials should work. If it doesn't kick in then try rebooting the device. Worked on a Huawei P9.

Answer (score 15):

Same thing happened to me.

All you have to do is go to "security" then go all the way down to "credential storage" then clear all credentials. Than you can go back and it's all done.

Comment: Go to `Settings` --> `Security` -->  Scroll to `Credential Storage` section  -->  Choose `Clear credentials`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple solution to this one. First of all change password lock to pattern lock. Then enter wrong pattern 5 times. You will see forgot password. Click that and enter account details. Then a screen will appear saying to change the lock type. Simply hit the back button and it will be automatically set to none.

Comment: Lol. I can't believe that this worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a red herring for me. I just had to enter my password one last time to get rid of the lock screen. I hadn't pushed on an unlocked door.

so go to Settings->Security->Lock Screen Enter Password

Comment: Thanks, this answer turned out to be the correct solution for me, I didn't understand what I had to do until I saw your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings and go to more, which is below data usage option. Then go to VPN and delete all vpns (jus clear it all). It is that which is blocking that screen lock setting.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to turn off the lock screen security somewhere in Settings>Security>Screen Lock and then change it to none or just a simple slide to unlock or whatever you want. This is how you get to it on my S3, but yours should be similar no matter what phone you have.

To fix your other issue, also in the Security tab on my phone, there should be a tab called "Device Administrators." When you go into this tab, it allows you to check and uncheck which apps have access. If you uncheck the app that is preventing you from changing this, it might solve your problem.

Comment: In the security screen, the "None" option is greyed out, with the text "Disabled by administrator, encryption policy, or credential storage." Same with the slide option.

Comment: Can you at least pick something like a slide to unlock or anything other than the pattern?

Comment: No, see above edit.

Comment: Are you not the administrator on the device? Check my updated answer.

Comment: The only thing in device administrators is Motorola Device Policy which is deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a way to remove the lock screen while keeping the certificate: set a pattern lock and try to unlock the phone with a "bad pattern" for 5-10 times, it will show you an error message, now select "Forgot Pattern?" and enter your gmail/password. After these steps the screen lock will be removed without removing the certificate. "

Comment: This works. Though, "none" option was still disabled until i tried @Merisol's answer

Answer (score 0):

**disable by administrator encryption policy, or credential storage**

if you are using Androidlost.com

1. go to andoridlost.com
2. Sign in with your device gmail account
3. click on Security option
4. lock phone option - clear all number & other
5. Unlock phone

Comment: Why would you think the questioner is using AndroidLost.com? They already said the problem is PdaNet+/FoxFi.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you've installed any 3rd party Device Management Applications, like Kaspersky Device Security, KNOX, etc.

I just solved my issue by deleting Kaspersky and all goes well.

Try to see which applications manage your device such as "Tracking your device against thieves so you could erase it remotely".

Answer (score -2):

Settings>Security>Device administrators
and you disables all administrators